# Getting 404 status code for form data with multipart file and fields in POST request using karate

Tags: karate

Could anyone please assist me to do form data with multipart file and multipart fields functionality using Karate API?

```
#configuring headers
Background: pre-condition
  * def functions = call read('classpath:supportingFiles/header.js')
  * configure headers = functions.getDocumentAPIHeaders()
#hitting the request
Scenario: upload file
  Given url _url
  * path 's3/upload?='
  * def fileText = read('orderValuationFileUpload.pdf')
  And multipart file document = { read:  'orderValuationFileUpload.pdf' }
  * multipart field s3Name = _Name
  * multipart field s3Key = _key
  And header Content-Type = 'multipart/form-data'
  When method post
  Then status 200
```

I am getting the error message below

```
Response:
Mixed: content-disposition: form-data; name="document"; filename="orderValuationFileUpload.pdf"
content-type: application/pdf; charset=UTF-8
content-length: 31199
Completed: true
IsInMemory: false
RealFile: C:\Users\admzn74\Workspace\benbroker_apitest\target\test-classes\b2bApplicationApi\appSubmission_F1\orderValuationFileUpload.pdf DefaultDeleteAfter: true

content-disposition: form-data; name="s3BucketName"; filename=""
content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
content-length: 57
Completed: true
IsInMemory: true

content-disposition: form-data; name="s3Key"; filename=""
content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
content-length: 74
Completed: true
IsInMemory: true


04:03:10.592 response time in milliseconds: 368
1 < 404
1 < Content-Type: multipart/form-data
1 < Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
1 < Access-Control-Expose-Headers: APIm-Debug-Trans-Id, X-RateLimit-Limit, X-RateLimit-Remaining, X-RateLimit-Reset, X-Global-Transaction-ID
1 < X-Backside-Transport: FAIL FAIL
1 < Connection: close
{ "httpCode":"404", "httpMessage":"Not Found", "moreInformation":"No resources match requested URI" }
```

Comment: multipart is hard. this is the only advice I can provide: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/1645#issuecomment-862502881

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this example for your use case :

https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/upload/upload.feature